# Passing a value between view Controllers

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, parameter-passing, popviewcontroller

Objective C - iPhone Application

I have 2 programatically instantiated UINavigationControllers

In controller 1 I push this View

```
-(IBAction) showStartDateCalendar 
{
 ModalSetDateController *setStartDate = [[ModalSetDateController alloc] init];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController: setStartDate animated:YES];
 [setStartDate release];

};
```

To push it back I was planning on doing something like this:

```
-(IBAction) PopMyViewControllerBack;

{
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

But how would I be able to get the value of the datepicker on ModalSetDateController
Is this the best way to handle adding a UIPickerview. I would prefer to not even have a UINavigationController do it. 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
-(IBAction)popMyViewControllerBack:(id)sender
```

and sender will be an instance of ModalSetDateController.

Comment: You can use [self presentModalViewController:setStartDate animated:YES] instead of using a UINavigationController.

Comment: Great solution John, so how do I grab the value and get rid of it

Comment: value = ((ModalSetDateController*)sender).someProperty;

Comment: Getting very close but still have a few issues: I am getting: [ModalSetDateController PopMyViewControllerBack]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x729c380
2010-12-17 21:16:39.767 iVT[4447:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ModalSetDateController PopMyViewControllerBack]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x729c380'

Comment: In my screen that is calling the ViewController that has the datepicker I have -(IBAction) showStartDateCalendar
{
 ModalSetDateController *setStartDate = [[ModalSetDateController alloc] init];
 [self presentModalViewController:setStartDate animated:YES];
  NSDate *value;
 value = ((ModalSetDateController*) setStartDate).udp_iVacationDatePicker.date; 
 [setStartDate release];

};

Comment: In my view that has the datepicker: -(IBAction)PopMyViewControllerBack:(id)sender;

{
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}